# how to batch while loop for windows node jenkins to update android sdk

Tags: android, batch-file, jenkins

***Updated:** how can i make this command work on a windows jenkins node in order to silently update android sdk?

```
( sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done ) | android update sdk --no-ui
```

This command works on a mac node in jenkins.

It installs all android sdk updates by supplying a 'y' to the 'android update sdk' command  and therefore accepts all licenses.

Now I try to port this command to a jenkins node running windows. But it complains about the 'while' keyword, which apparently doesn't exist on windows.

So how can I convert this sleeping loop which adds a 'y' at every licence prompt triggered by the 'android update sdk' command?

Best Regards,

Comment: I don't get what exactly you want to achieve. `( sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done )` is not batch code. Please explain how you want your script to work.

Comment: ok i've updated my question; i hope my intentions are clearer now thanks in advance